# C#,WPF integrated user control

Tags: c#, wpf, elementhost

Got a winform in project **A** (Main project) and which hosts a wpf user control and is maintained under different project called **B**

On click of a button on user control ,I wanted to query server which is in project "**C**" and retrieve data and show it on hosted wpf user control. I know its a bad coding practice to put a reference to s project "**C**" in project **B** which includes only custom controls .Any alternative  thots would be appreciated...

Comment: Can you be a bit more specific on what you want to do? What have you tried?

Comment: basically wanted to show some data on wpf user control by retrieving it from server .

Comment: Why do you think it's bad practise to put in a dependency that is (apparently) needed to deliver your required functionality?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To minimize project dependencies, create an interface in your control project (B) that reflects the operations your control requires.

Implement a class in your client (A) project that implements this interface (which will obtain the information you need from your data project (C) and pass it back through the interface method).

Pass the service class (implementing the interface) constructed in A to your control B when you initialize the control.

Answer (score 0):

You make another project that is just a class library that can be shared across all three projects.  You'll put the interfaces and/or the class implementations that need to be shared between the projects in the class library and then just use those in the server and the user-control projects.